# Stone-Weierstrass theorem with "nowhere-vanishing" premise

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, weierstrass-approximation

Let $K$ be a compact space and $\mathscr A\subseteq C(K,\mathbb R)$ be a subalgebra. Let us assume the "usual" form of the real Stone-Weierstrass theorem: If $\mathscr A$ separates points in $K$ and **contains a nonzero constant function**, then it is uniformly dense in $C(K,\mathbb R)$.

Rudin proves this with weaker premises (hence, his version is stronger), namely, replacing the bold part with the requirement that the $\mathscr A$ vanish nowhere (baby Rudin, Theorem 7.32). *I'd like to prove Rudin's stronger version, but in the fastest way possible, given that I've already proven the usual form given above.* In particular, I only need to prove that $1\in\overline{\mathscr A}$. I think this can be done without repeating all of Rudin's proof.

---

Current progress/idea: Repeat the first part of Rudin's proof, which uses the Weierstrass theorem (for polynomials) to show that $f,g\in\overline{\mathscr A}\implies\max(f,g)\in\overline{\mathscr A}$. The nowhere-vanishing condition can be used to find functions $f_x\in\mathscr A$ such that $f_x(x)=1.$ Using compactness of $K$ and closure of $\mathscr A$ under finite maximums, we can constrct a function $f\in\mathscr A$ such that $f(x)>1-\varepsilon$ for small $\varepsilon>0$. Using some constructions like this and combining them appropriately, I imagine we can find a function that falls uniformly within $\varepsilon$ of $1$, but so far I'm stuck here.

Comment: How can you use the Weierstrass theorem for polynomials, though?  If you don't know constants are in $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{A}$ may not be closed under composition with polynomials (only polynomials without a constant term).

Comment: @EricWofsey The way Rudin uses it is indirect. We don't know constants are in $\mathscr A$, but given $f\in\overline{\mathscr A}$ with $a=\|f\|$, we can construct a polynomial that approximates $x\mapsto|x|$ on $[-a,a]$, and then we use the coefficients to construct a function in $\mathscr A$ that approximates $|f|$.

Comment: But in order to do that you would need to know those coefficients do not include a constant term.

Comment: @EricWofsey If $p_n(x)\to|x|$ then $p_n(0)\to0$, so wlog $p_n(0)=0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm confused. The coefficients are real numbers, and we assume $\mathscr A$ is a real subalgebra of $C(K,\mathbb R)$, so it is closed under real scalar multiplication.

Comment: But if $p$ is a polynomial and you want to construct $p(f)$, how do you get the constant term of $p(f)$?

Comment: No, there is a problem (easily finagled). The problem is that if say $p(t)=2t+1$ then $p\circ f=1+2f$. No, the $2f$ is no problem, but where do you get the $1$?

Comment: Ah I see. If $p_n$ is a sequence of polynomials approximating $|x|$, consider $p_n'(t)=p_n(t)-p_n(0).$ I'm copying from Rudin, Corollary 7.27.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do.  Let $f\in\mathcal{A}$ be a nowhere vanishing function.  Replacing $f$ with $f^2$, we may assume $f>0$ everywhere, and scaling $f$, we may assume $f\geq 1$ everywhere.  Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)=1$ for all $x\geq 1$.  By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, we can uniformly approximate $g$ with polynomials $p_n$ on the interval $[0,\|f\|]$.  Subtracting the constant terms from these $p_n$, we get polynomials $q_n$ which still uniformly approximate $g$, since the constant terms are the values $p_n(0)$ which converge to $g(0)=0$.  Since $q_n$ does not have a constant term, $q_n(f)\in\mathcal{A}$ for each $n$.  Since $f$ takes values in $[1,\|f\|]$ everywhere, $q_n(f)$ converges uniformly to $g(f)$ which is just the constant function $1$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to say.